# Log out from website that uses basic authentication

Tags: python, flask, basic-authentication

I need to do a logout button. I use Flask and Python and my website uses basic authentication so as to log in. I found out that the only possible way to log out is to close a browser (which is not what I'm looking for) or to change already entered login and password doing something like this:

```
user:pass@127.0.0.1:8000
```

It works when I input that phrase in URL but I'd like to do it programmatically.

My Python code:

```
@app.route('/logout')
@auth.login_required
def logout():
    urlparameter = "user:pass@127.0.0.1:8000"
    return Response(render_template('logout.html', urlparameter=urlparameter, mimetype='text/html'))
```

HTML button:

```
<a href="{{ urlparameter }}">Logout</a>
```

However, it doesn't work. How should I change it? Thanks

Comment: I guess you want `redirect("http://user:pass@url")`

Comment: Yes, I want to redirect and also display a logout.html file and then not be able to browse a website

Comment: Yes, I've seen this but it doesn't solve my problem..

Comment: HTTP Basic Auth is handled by user agent (browser), and basically does not allow logging out (since **each request includes username and password**). To be able to log user out, you have to have a user session.

Comment: As I said passing different values like e.g. `user:pass@127.0.0.1:8000` allows to (let's say) log out.. I mean when I want to browse my website again I need to enter correct login and password.. I believe it is possible to do using Python and Flask..